# MUI DataGrid how to pass data from Row to another page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a table showing a list of users. When a row is clicked, I would like the user's detail to show up on a new page.

So far, I have it so when the row is clicked, it navigates to the Individual User page. I'm not sure how to get the user's data onto the Individual user's page though.

```
function Users() {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);

  const handleOnCellClick = (params) => {
    setUserList(params);
    history('/pages/IndividualUsers');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/users').then((response) => {
      setUserList(response.data);
    });
  });

  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'first_name',
      headerName: 'first name',
      width: 100,
    },
    {
      field: 'last_name',
      headerName: 'last name',
    },
    {
      field: 'email',
      headerName: 'email',
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      field: 'creation_date',
      headerName: 'Creation Date',
      width: 250,
    },
  ];

  return (
   
        <DataGrid
          rows={userList}
          columns={columns}
          getRowId={(row) => row.email}
          pageSize={10}
          onCellClick={handleOnCellClick}
        />
   
  
  );
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `createSearchParams` and navigate like this:

```
import { useNavigate, createSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const handleOnCellClick = (params) => {
    const currentRow = params.row;
    const options = {
      pathname: "/pages/IndividualUsers",
      search: `?${createSearchParams(currentRow)}`
    };
    navigate(options, { replace: true });
};
```

and in your individual user route, you can get the search params from `location` like this:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-haze-jdc3tg?file=/src/Users.js:943-956) for a live working example.